# Php - check if rectangles overlap

Tags: php, intersection, rectangles

I am using the below mentioned code to find out if the rectangles on image map intersect or overlap but I am getting wrong results. Y coordinates increase from top towards bottom. The dimensions of rectangles vary.

```
$r1 = array('MapX1' => 10, 'MapX2' => 10, 'MapY1' => 30, 'MapY2' => 30);
$r2 = array( 'MapX1' => 20, 'MapX2' => 20, 'MapY1' => 50, 'MapY2' => 50);

function intersectRect($r1, $r2) {
        /*
        left: x1,
        right: x1 + x2,
        top: y1,
        bottom: y1 + y2,
      */

$r1['MapX2'] = $r1['MapX2'] - $r1['MapX1'];
$r2['MapX2'] = $r2['MapX2'] - $r2['MapX1'];

$r1['MapY1'] = $r1['MapY2'] - $r1['MapY1'];
$r2['MapY2'] = $r1['MapY2'] - $r1['MapY1'];

        $a = array('left' => $r1['MapX1'], 'right' => $r1['MapX1'] + $r1['MapX2'], 'top' => $r1['MapY1'], 
            'bottom' => $r1['MapY1'] + $r1['MapY2']);
        $b = array('left' => $r2['MapX1'], 'right' => $r2['MapX1'] + $r2['MapX2'], 'top' => $r2['MapY1'], 
            'bottom' => $r2['MapY1'] + $r2['MapY2']);
        if(
            $a['right'] < $b['left'] || 
            $a['left'] > $b['right'] || 
            $a['bottom'] < $b['top'] || 
            $a['top'] > $b['bottom']
          ){ 
            return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

echo intersectRect($r1, $r2);
```

Please help me figure out what am i doing wrong here?

The above code does not work correct for the below rectangles:
Gives 1 but should return 0.

```
$r1 = array(
    [MapX1] => 536
    [MapX2] => 567
    [MapY1] => 199
    [MapY2] => 237
)
$r2 = array
(
    [MapX1] => 430
    [MapX2] => 453
    [MapY1] => 141
    [MapY2] => 153
)
```

Comment: The if statement seems to compare top to bottom twice, instead of comparing left to right the second time.

Comment: @MartinCook Please have a look. I have edited the code now.

Comment: @cartina what results are you getting, and what results are you expecting? From my calculations, it appears that this should be returning 1 for your rectangles - is this what you're getting?

Comment: Are these rectangle supposed to yield 1 or 0 in this instance?

Comment: @RamRaider the function returns 0 if rectangles do not intersect and 1 if they do

Comment: @crazyloonybin yes it returns 1 if they overlap but am getting wrong results

Comment: @cartina but they do overlap, so returning 1 is correct.

Comment: Seems to work for the rectangles I tried... can you post an example of two rectangles that gives the wrong answer?

Comment: For rectangle `a`, your left, right, top, bottom values are 10, 20, 30, 60. For rectangle `b`, the values are 20, 40, 50, 100. If you put those into the if statement, none of the conditions are met, so your else clause is fired, returning the value of 1.

Comment: @crazyloonybin I have added the example where it does not work

Comment: @MartinCook I have addd the example where am getting results wrong. Please help me.

Comment: @cartina if you calculate the values again, `$r1`  has left, right, top, bototm values of 567, 1103, 199, 436. `$r2` has values 430, 883, 141, 294. Again, none of the conditions in the if statement are met, so the else clause is fired, returning 1.

Comment: @cartina I think you're getting confused - you're X2 and Y2 values are actually the _width and height_ values, **NOT** the X2 and Y2 _coordinates_.

Comment: @crazyloonybin So I am wrong with the overlap check conditions? What should be the conditions then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160279/discussion-between-crazyloonybin-and-cartina).

Comment: @cartina Those two rectangles do overlap, so they should give a 1, so the code is correct.

Comment: @crazyloonybin that 's what I am doing. What if I calculate width & height as under:  width : x2 -x1
                 height : y2 -y2, assuming X1Y1 to be top left and X2Y2 as bottom right coordinates?

Comment: @crazyloonybin thanks a million. it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comments and discussion on chat, it appears that you're expecting the `X2` and `Y2` values to be co-ordinates, but your code is treating them as widths and heights respectively.

If you want the code to treat them as co-ordinates instead, your code would be changed to the following:

```
$r1 = array('MapX1' => 536, 'MapX2' => 567, 'MapY1' => 199, 'MapY2' => 237);
$r2 = array( 'MapX1' => 430, 'MapX2' => 453, 'MapY1' => 141, 'MapY2' => 153);

function intersectRect($r1, $r2) {
    /*
    left: x1,
    right: x2,
    top: y1,
    bottom: y2,
  */

    $a = array('left' => $r1['MapX1'], 'right' => $r1['MapX2'], 'top' => $r1['MapY1'], 
        'bottom' => $r1['MapY2']);
    $b = array('left' => $r2['MapX1'], 'right' => $r2['MapX2'], 'top' => $r2['MapY1'], 
        'bottom' => $r2['MapY2']);
    if(
        $a['right'] < $b['left'] || 
        $a['left'] > $b['right'] || 
        $a['bottom'] < $b['top'] || 
        $a['top'] > $b['bottom']
      ){ 
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

echo intersectRect($r1, $r2);
```

Note that I have changed the code where you are declaring `$a` and `$b` so that it takes the `X2` and `Y2` values directly, instead of adding them to the `X1` and `Y1` values. I've also used the rectangles that you added in the edit to your question, rather than the original rectangles you defined.